# Create a Graph from points in a Grid that contains holes

Tags: actionscript-3, graph, 2d

I've got a continuous plane (2-D) containing polygonal obstacles. I am uniformly sampling the plane at discrete positions to create a uniform grid of points. The grid does not have points where obstacles lie (i.e. holes where ever an obstacle is) as shown in the image below.

(Please view the image at http://i48.tinypic.com/2efnblg.png for a clear idea of what I'm attempting to accomplish. I couldn't embed it.)

Can anyone point me to some good implementations with optimal worst-case time-complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using recursion.